# Migrating stripe express into stripe standard

Tags: stripe-payments

I already have a stripe standard account but a platform created a stripe espress account for me. Even though I used the same email address for both, they are now two separate accounts managed in two separate places with two separate dashboards even though both are for my business. Is there a way of migrating the express data into the standard account? My goal is to close the Express account and have All my transactions and management in one location

I had come across some documentation that indicated creating an express account with the same email as an existing standard account would automatically merge the accounts but I can't seem to find that documentation again.